# What happens first: min() in selector or where in condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created the following query

```
select
    c.id as eid,
    c.created,
    e.class_id,
    min(e.event_time),
    min(cn.create_time) as lead_date
from
    bm_emails.cid378 c
left join bm_sets.event378 e on e.eid = c.id
left join bm_sets.conversion378 cn on cn.eid = c.id
where e.class_id = 36
group by eid, created, class_id
```

What happens first when SQL runs the query? The `where` clause or the `min(e.event_time)`?

If the where clause comes after then great.

If not is there a way to reverse this so that the `min(e.event_time)` get's pulled first and then have the where condition apply to that subset of min dates?

Ideally without use of a sub query.

**** Example following responses:**

If I sign up on the site and trigger an event with class_id 40, then a week later I come to the site and trigger an event with class_id 36, then I should NOT be included in the results. Right now it looks like I would be included since SQL will first filter on where clause, and then apply min date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the result of your Min in your condition, however, you will need to use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

Reference: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

Comment: Interesting. So having happens AFTER aggregation?

Comment: Exactly, it's meant to handle cases like yours.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense logically. I cannot actually verify on our server it keep kicking me off with a time out message. Presumably "having" involves more work for the server and I'll need to resort to writing a script to get my data. Accepting but unable to verify the solution worked.

Comment: Our dev added a key to one of our tables and this now runs. Results as expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The WHERE clause must be executed first, because in your query, MIN runs on the results of the query.  You'll need a join or a subquery to do what you want.

Comment: Hi Richard thanks for clarifying that. When you say a join or subquery, how would I do it with a join?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what your query is trying to do

Comment: Appended an example tot he question

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE`statement does fire first.  It limits the records returned, and then the `MIN` is applied.  Also, in your query, the `WHERE e.class_id = 36` make the `left outer join` act like an `inner join`.  If you are looking for the `MIN` value in the table, and then the rest of the results you will have to do a sub query.  Something like:

```
select
    c.id as eid,
    c.created,
    e.class_id,
    min(e.event_time),
    (SELECT min(cn1.create_time) FROM bm_sets.conversion378 cn1) as lead_date
from
    bm_emails.cid378 c
left join bm_sets.event378 e on e.eid = c.id
left join bm_sets.conversion378 cn on cn.eid = c.id
where e.class_id = 36
group by eid, created, class_id
```